# i want to load multiple models in a particular function in a controller in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i tried to set $uses in cakePhp3, it's working in cakePhp2.6 but not in 3

```
public $uses = array('model1', 'model2', 'model3', .... );
```

but i get error like

```
{
    "message": "Call to a member function find() on boolean",
    "url": "/JobPosts/Test/1042.json",
    "code": 500,
    "file": "/home/task24/public_html/clientApi/src/Controller/JobPostsController.php",
    "line": 1304
}
```

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `$uses` anymore in Cake 3.

```
$this->loadModel('MyModel');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to load all models using **array_map** function

```
array_map([$this, 'loadModel'], ['Product', 'Orders', 'OrderItem']);   //Pass each element of the array to loadModel with is accessable through $this object.
```

Or create a function in your **AppController**, like

```
function loadModels($models = []) {
   foreach($models as $model) {
       $this->loadModel($model);
   }
}
//Then you can access this function anywhere from any controller function (Controller which are extending AppController)
$this->loadModels(['Products', 'Orders', 'SO-ON']);
```